# PayPal API adaptive pay Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to make test payment with PayPal API, but response is following:

```
{ responseEnvelope: 
   { timestamp: '2013-08-12T03:28:07.503-07:00',
     ack: 'Failure',
     correlationId: '960a8b60a602e',
     build: '6941298' },
  error: 
   [ { errorId: '520003',
       domain: 'PLATFORM',
       subdomain: 'Application',
       severity: 'Error',
       category: 'Application',
       message: 'Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.' } ],
  httpStatusCode: 200 }
```

I created sandbox business account and make request with account credentials, but have failure.

Comment: Check your credentials also see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

Comment: tnx, I try to use credentials from developers.paypal.com, not from sandbox.paypal.com and everything is working properly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to use credentials from [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com), not from sandbox.paypal.com and everything is working properly now

Answer (score 4):

I was using the sandbox account, client ID and signature under the REST API. The correct sandbox account is as follows:

- Log in to developer.paypal.com
- Select Application from the top menu.
- Click on sand box accounts from the left menu.
- Here you can create sand box accounts for testing and in these accounts you can have profile. In the profile under the api credentials tab you will find the correct credentials.
- I have attached a Screen capture.

Hope it helps.

---

This answer was provided by Abhisheik at wpmudev.

Note : My account is in state "Approved Conditionally" which I though was the issue. Sandbox development can, in fact, continue even in this state.

Big thanks to Abhisheik. If you read the thread, he want way above and beyond.