# Add custom header to AFNetworking, what am I dong wrong?

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, paypal, afnetworking

The curl method is like below and I am adding custom header to AFNetworking like below. But curl method is working but AFNetworking not. What am I doing wrong?

curl method:

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: someUserId" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: somePassword" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: someSignature" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: someAPPID" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
 -H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
 -d "payKey=someAPPKEY&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US"

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:kPaypalClientId forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:kPaypalPassword forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:kPaypalSignature forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:appId forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"NV" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT"];

[manager GET:@"https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails" parameters:@{@"payKey": payKey, @"requestEnvelope.errorLanguage": @"en_US"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

I am not getting error from failure block. But this returned as responseObject but if i use the curl method above. it's response is success. and the header value are the same.:

```
{
    error =     (
                {
            category = Application;
            domain = PLATFORM;
            errorId = 520003;
            message = "Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.";
            severity = Error;
            subdomain = Application;
        }
    );
    responseEnvelope =     {
        ack = Failure;
        build = 9641252;
        correlationId = 8f5818a80ec65;
        timestamp = "2014-02-14T22:37:30.448-08:00";
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `NSError` description?

Comment: no afnetworking error. just paypal error returned. does it mean the value not sent to the paypal server?

Comment: Can you post the value of this line please? `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);`

Comment: You are setting correct the headers, what is the response?

Comment: @jbouaziz I don't get error from failure block.

Comment: The `X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT` header doesn't seem to be the same for `curl` and your `manager. Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18185433/1835155 please? It seems that somebody already had the same problem as you.

Comment: @jbouaziz I don't think that's the case. It's a response data format. and if I didn't set the format correctly, the server won't return json object back.

Comment: Did you try using other credentials from the paypal website? I posted a link in my last comment.

Comment: @jbouaziz You mean not using the sandbox account? But if the curl method is working, why not the afnetworking method won't work?

Comment: @jbouaziz If I use the live account, could I still use the sandbox to test the payment?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request in curl and a GET request in AFNetworking, check your curl request using -v.

Comment: I am getting the same error. Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect. even I have replace the get with post request.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with paypal api. Did you update X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT field? cause your sending your params as json body

Comment: I am using the default NV value for  X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT which I copied from the developer document of paypal. Should I change it to json or what else?

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite it with NSURSSession, and it worked. It seems I didn't get it right using AfNetWorking.